# Is there a way to update attributes files directly in chef server without uploading cookbook again

Tags: chef, knife, attributes

I am using **hosted chef** environment in **windows**.I need to update the attribute file during each chef client run. Currently ,I update it manually and upload the cookbook in chef server.Is there any way in which I can directly edit the attribute file in chef server without having to upload the entire cookbook.

Thanks for your help

Comment: why would you want to edit the attributes.rb file after every run?  If you give a little more detail, we can probably help you accomplish the same thing in a much cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

`knife node edit host.example.com`

allows you to modify the `normal` attribute hierarchy of that node. The same can be done (IIRC also in hosted Chef) in the web interface.

However, this is very bad practice - you later never know, who set which attributes.